# Открыть/передать данные с одной формы в другой

Tags: access, vba

Есть две формы. В одной из них отображаются данные с таблицы (ФИО, логин, дата входа, и т.д.), все поля заблокированы для изменения. При двойном клике должна открыться другая форма в которой открыты для редактирования те поля на которых был даблклик.
Я в одну форму пытался повесить следующий код. К примеру поле "ФИО" содержит такой код:

```
   Private Sub ФИО_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
     Dim stDocName As String
     Dim stLinkCriteria As String
     stDocName = "Main2"
     stLinkCriteria = "[ФИО=]" & "'" & Me![ФИО] & "'"
   DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
   DoCmd.Close acForm, "Main"
  End Sub
```

но он не работает, выдает ошибка синтаксиса, пропущен оператор в выражении запроса '[ФИО=]'LoremIpsum". Когда исправил следующим образом:

```
stLinkCriteria = "[ФИО]=" & "'" & Me![ФИО] & "'" - открывается просто пустая форма.
```

Как реализовать передачу данных, хотя бы в каком направлении рыть?

Comment: `stLinkCriteria` это что за параметр? OpenArgs?

Comment: добавьте к вопросу код открытия и загрузки формы Main2

Comment: @Anatol что то вы меня запутали.. что значит код открытия? я в мейне2 еще никакой не прописывал.
stLinkCriteria - насколько я понял - параметр который задает критерий фильтра и передает его дальше в форму которая открывается.

Answer (score 1):

> открывается просто пустая форма

Ну так проверьте её RecordSource - сразу увидите, что не так, почему на форму не выводятся записи. Ну и проверьте её свойства - например, не установлено ли свойство DataEntry...

А ещё можно передать требуемые параметры, например, через Public-переменные модуля формы - установить их значения в требуемые, а форма уже при отображении использует их для собственной настройки. При этом, конечно, не получится использовать DoCMD, надо будет явно загружать форму, отображать её и передавать ей фокус с помощью всякоразных Load, Show и т.п. Но это и правильнее, на самом деле, к тому же так может грузиться не абстрактная форма, а конкретный экземпляр её класса.

Comment: а можно краткий ликбез о том как пользоваться рекордсетом, впервые о нем слышу

Comment: В данной задаче им пользоваться не надо от слова "вообще". Да и не говорил тут пока никто и ничего о рекордсетах...

Comment: хорошо, а как вообще тогда?

Comment: а если я воспользуюсь OpenArgs?